# Webpack mix, Vue - output files on cdn subdomain

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js

I am struggling with webpack. I want to have the compiled files in public-cdn folder. However, the following code creates files in several different locations. Including E:\cdn. Chunks, app.js, css files - everything in different location.

Paths:

main folder:  www/Project
laravel public:  www/Project/public
cdn folder:  www/Project/public-cdn

webpack.mix.js

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    output : {
        path : '/public-cdn/',
        publicPath : 'http://cdn.ywg.localhost/',
        chunkFilename : 'js/[name].js'
    },
});


mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/styles.scss', '../public-cdn/css')
    .options({processCssUrls: false
    });

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/invoice.scss', '../public-cdn/css')
    .options({processCssUrls: false
    });

mix.js('resources/assets/js/frontApps.js', '../public-cdn/js')
    .extract(['vue']);
```

I tried experimenting with Path and PublicPath parameters. PublicPath doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more experimenting, I think I found a solution. The issue might be caused by laravel mix which set's the "public" folder.

I added:

```
mix.setPublicPath('public-cdn/');
```

and it seems to be working well now.